# Loading Ajax one after another

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a few ajax calls on a page, well more than a few and I have been tasked with making it less server intensive.

This is the current set up of the code:

```
$.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'visits', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'},function(data){
    //stuff
};

$.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'terms', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'},function(data){
    //stuff
};
$.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'usage', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'},function(data){
    //stuff
};
$.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'content', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'},function(data){
    //stuff
};
```

And this goes on for 15 other calls.

When I monitor the server the activity is way to high.

**What would be the best way to load this one after another and reduce the strain on the server?**

Comment: Can you not just create one call and get all?

Comment: Once that data has been passed through, each one is handled in a different way. Some generate charts, some tables and other set variables and pass things to other functions to run.

Comment: why not do all the stuff in single function

Answer (score 0):

Use jQueries [deferred.then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

```
$.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'visits', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'}).then(function(data1) {
    //stuff
    $.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'terms', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'}).then(function(data2){
         //stuff
         //etc.
    };
});
```

Or you could devide your code in some logical functions returning a Deferred:

```
function someName() {
    return $.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'visits', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'}).then(function(data1) {
        //stuff
    });
}

function someOtherName() {
    return $.getJSON('charts_ajax.php',{a : 'terms', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'}).then(function(data2){
         //stuff
    });
}

someName().then(someOtherName).then(etc).then(function() {
    console.log("done");
);
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite it as a single call/response, and parse it out, would be a guess

Answer (score -1):

$.getJSON is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax(
{
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

And according to the documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) :

> async (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need
>   synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests
>   and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.
>   Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8,
>   the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you
>   must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the
>   corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the
>   deprecated jqXHR.success().

So you can rewrite like this :

```
$.ajax(
{
  dataType: "json",
  async: false,
  url: 'charts_ajax.php',
  data: {a : 'visits', rangeStartDate : '<?=$_POST["rangeStartDate"] ?>', rangeEndDate : '<?= $_POST["rangeEndDate"] ?>'},
  success: function(data)
  {
        //stuff
  };
});
```

Comment: IMHO, use setInterval is a better idea, or like jmadsen said, a single ajax call.